# Cannot access my first sub-site in a multisite

Tags: multisite

I'm getting the dreaded:

```
 “Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page”
```

error when i login to my only subsite as administrator for that site. Even when i login with my main admin account i cant get to the dashboard of my sub-site or, indeed, any subsite administration page. WP kicks me back onto the login page for the subsite and logging in produces the error message. sometimes it shows an error mssg stating that **Cookies must be enabled**; but cookies most definitely ARE enabled!

I only have one subsite in my network and one user for all sub-sites; that user is set by default to Administrator. My own account (Main Admin/WP Key-holder) has full control overall sub-sites. What could be wrong here? the sub-sites were created properly  - wildcard DNS setup in my SiteGround hosting etc ...

My primary site uses the free `Lets Encrypt SSL` Do i need to be accessing my sub-domains via SSL https and should i specify https protocol in WordPress when adding the subsite URLs?

Comment: A free SSL usually only covers the main domain - so either `example.com` or `www.example.com`. When you set up subsites as subdomains - as in `subsite1.example.com` - you must also apply a separate SSL certificate for them, unless you have a wildcard SSL that applies to any subdomain of your site. That is most likely the issue. Forcing everything to be SSL will ensure a bit better security and also prevent permission issues. You might also want to consider making your site a sub*folder* MultiSite - that way your one SSL certificate covers everything, no further setup needed.

Comment: I've already setup SSL on the sub-domain also from my SiteGround account its easy to do. Directory-based domains isn't an option since we have future functionality which relies on the sub-domain based URLs

Comment: @WebElaine Lets Encrypt SSL are usually wildcard (infinite subdomains).

Answer (score 1):

[resolved] fixed issue by removing site and associated user a re-creating